# Error building GLib

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, glib

Im trying to build GLib-2.4.0 using the makefile.

I get this error:

```
    gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -I.. -DG_LOG_DOMAIN=\"GLib\" -DG_DISABLE_CAST_CHECKS -DG_DISABLE_DEPRECATED -DGLIB_COMPILATION -pthreads -g -O2 -Wall -MT gatomic.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/gatomic.Tpo -c gatomic.c
-fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/gatomic.o
    /var/tmp//cctTsmw7.s:103:Incorrect register `%rdx' used with `l' suffix
    make[3]: *** [gatomic.lo] Error 1
    make[2]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
    make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
    make: *** [install] Error 2
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It could be a compiler strictness change, maybe try compiling with gcc circa 2004?

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that a newer version of glib will fix this problem.

However, if you're stuck with 2.4 for some reason, this was discussed in the gtk-devel-list at http://www.mail-archive.com/gtk-devel-list@gnome.org/msg10924.html ... here is the workaround that was reported there.

Here is the workaround that was successful for two users in that thread:

> Ah yes, I think I have stumbled on this as well.  This is probably
>   caused because the default jhbuildrc for the Mac forces a build for
>   the 486:
>
> > When building on intel, force build to be 486, since glib won't
> >     enable asm atomic operations otherwise.
>
> try:
>        _f = os.popen("uname -p")
>        if _f.read().startswith("i386"):
>        append_autogenargs("glib", "--build=i486-apple-darwin")
>
> I changed the last line to:
>
> ```
>   append_autogenargs("glib", "--build=x86_64-apple-darwin")
> ```
>
> And that fixed it for me.   (If you have a Mac with a Core2 processor,
>   the user land will be in 64-bit in Snow Leopard).